# Added panel not showing up in frame (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on making a battleship game board using swing in java. I've added the panel (i.e. the grid or the game board) to the window but it still won't show up. I've pasted the code below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class board {

private static JFrame window;
private static JPanel[][] grid;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("GAME BOARD");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    grid = new JPanel[10][10];
    for (int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j< 10; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new JPanel();
            grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
            grid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            grid[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
            window.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default calling `JFrame#add()` will add to the `JFrame`s *contentPane* which has a default layout of [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Have a read on [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You probably want to either use a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) depending on your needs.

I'd also suggest overriding `getPreferredSize` and returning the dimensions as opposed to calling `setPreferredSize`.

You then would do something like this:

```
// this jpanel will hold the all grid jpanels could also use new FlowLayout()
JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
grid = new JPanel[10][10];
    for (int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j< 10; j++) {
           grid[i][j] = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(25, 25);
                }
            };
            ...
            container.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

window.add(container);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

Have a look at this question which is also about [creating a layout for a battleship game](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380979/1133011). I'd suggest using something more lightweight and easier to customize like `JLabel` to represent each square.

[image]

You may also want to read up on [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Essentially all *Swing* components should be created on the EDT via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestApp {

    public TestApp() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
         // create JFrame and other Swing components here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that. Now there's another issue I'm facing. I added the player and enemy boards to the window but they're fully filling it. Can't get their size smaller or any space between the two panels.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your frame size

```
window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
```

Comment: Thanks man! That solved another issue I was concerned about.

Comment: @PhebosBelmont You shouldn't be calling `setPreferredSize` on your `JFrame` or any component for that matter, using  a `LayoutManager`, overriding `getPreferredSize` if needed for `JPanel`s or `JLablel`s which have no "actual content" and then calling `pack()` on the `JFrame` is the correct way to go about it