# Moving labels in nested panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, setbounds

[image]I've made two grids and added them to a window using nested panels. The only issue is that I can't move the grid in the center and can't get the labels under their respective grids. Tried using setBounds but that's not working. Any advice? I've added an image of the current state. I want to display the player and opponent label under the first and second grid respectively.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Battleship.exe");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    
    P1_container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
    P1_container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    P1_container.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5));
    
    compContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
    compContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    compContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 5));
    
    grid = new JPanel[10][10];
    for (int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j< 10; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new JPanel();
            grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
            grid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2));
            grid[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,35));
            P1_container.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    enemyGrid = new JPanel[10][10];
    for (int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
        for (int j =0; j< 10; j++) {
            enemyGrid[i][j] = new JPanel();
            enemyGrid[i][j].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            enemyGrid[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));
            enemyGrid[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));
            compContainer.add(enemyGrid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    layout.setHgap(150);
    mainPanel = new JPanel(layout); 
    
    mainPanel.add(P1_container);
    mainPanel.add(compContainer);
    
    player = new JLabel("PLAYER");
    player.setBounds(100, 410, 5, 5);
    
    opponent = new JLabel("OPPONENT");
    opponent.setBounds(100, 410, 5, 5);
    
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    panel.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(player, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panel.add(opponent, BorderLayout.WEST);
    
    window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: *"Any advice?"* 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The OP is using layout managers and nested panels. I agree that I would like to see a picture of his intended layout, because I can't picture what he wants to do.

Comment: The role of layout managers is to set bounds automatically. Let the layout manger do its work and do not set bounds manually.

Comment: Ok. I can share a screenshot of the current window

Comment: To get you started remove `opponent.setBounds(100, 410, 5, 5);` and replace `panel.add(opponent, BorderLayout.WEST);`  with `enemyGrid[5][5].add(opponent);`

Comment: @c0der I tried using flowLayout instead but it's still the same

Comment: Please apply the suggested changes and see the result.

Comment: @c0der I did apply the suggested changes but now the label is showing up in the center of the grid not underneath it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please mark your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436163/added-panel-not-showing-up-in-frame-java/65436717#65436717) as solved if they are. People have taken the time to help you out and it's the least you can do. Read here for more information on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

You are STILL calling `setPreferredSize` you should instead override `getPreferredSize` and ONLY where necessary. If your grid `JPanel`s are sized via `getPreferredSize` there is no need to call `setPreferredSize` on their respective containers or the `JFrame` also you are still not creating your Swing components on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

As others have mentioned, you cannot use `setBounds` when using a `LayoutManager`. To achieve what you want, you need to nest layouts, as you have been told before.

So you probably want to create two `JPanel`s with a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). These two new containers will hold each grid and its label respectively:

```
JPanel p1Container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p1Container.add(P1_container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
p1Container.add(player, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JPanel opponentContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
opponentContainer.add(compContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
opponentContainer.add(opponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

...

panel.add(p1Container);
panel.add(opponentContainer);
```

Also the below code makes no sense:

```java
panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
panel.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(player, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(opponent, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

By default, a `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout` so `BorderLayout.XXX` means nothing here.
Again take the time to read [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) but the code I showed corrects this by not passing in any extra parameters to `add()`

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I'm a beginner to java and stack overflow and must've forgotten about approving the answer so excuse me for that. I'm still new to swing concepts and am experimenting with different methods so everything makes sense to me. Plus, I'm not finished reading through the links you've sent me. Also, I've already tried the solution you've sent me and it's throwing an exception but I'm working my way around it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's cool man but yeah definitely accept answers that's solve your question makes people more likely to answer you. What's the exception?

Comment: it says "Cannot read field "parent" because "comp" is null". But it's ok I'm looking at it. Gonna try debugging and see what's up.

Comment: I solved that issue. Thanks again for the assist.